# Azure VM Backups failure: CopyingVHDsFromBackUpVaultTakingLongTime

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, backup

For last few days, backup of a Linux VM in Azure is failing daily with following error message and code. We have not made any change in VM or Recovery Service Vault.

**Error Code:** CopyingVHDsFromBackUpVaultTakingLongTime

**Error Message:** Copying backed up data from vault timed out

Backup job completes the VM snapshot task successfully but transfer data to vault step runs endlessly for over 24 error and eventually fails with a timeout message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error usually comes when disk size more than 1TB. As of now, we are not supporting more than 1TB. If your environment has disks more than 1 TB, I suggest you remove the disks which are more than 1TB and then run the backup job.

Comment: yes, the VM has a disk of size 2TB attached to it. I will check if we can do anything about it.